# Customising user credentials in resource owner password credential grant type

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization, token, access-token, bearer-token

I have implemented token Authorization of type ***Resource Owner Password Credential*** type in web api and it's working completely fine.
E.g. `{ grant_type : password, userid: usr1, password: pwd }`
And it sends me response with access token.

Now I have got new requirement to implement for Authorization using entitytype (1 or 2). 
E.g `{ grant_type : password, userid: usr1, password: pwd, entityType: 1 }`

Is there any way that I can customise the credentials and still continue using my so far implemented token Authorization or do I have to change the entire approach altogether. If I have to change entire approach, what it would be?

Thank you.